# How to fill an empty column from a dataframe, based on conditions from more than 2 other dataframes, all with different lengths?

Tags: r

I have this first dataframe (named "fish_12") with 74610 rows, each row having data on marine fish specimens. The first column is the name of the species each specimen belongs to (there are many specimens belonging to the same species throughout the dataframe), the second column, BIN, is a sort of ID number for each species, and then I have the name of the collector of each specimens, the country it was collected from and an empty column grade that I want to fill.

```
     species        |    BIN      |    collectors  |  country      | grade
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tilapia guineensis  |BOLD:AAL5979 |    C.D. Nwani  |     Nigeria   | NA
Tilapia zillii      |BOLD:AAB9042 |    C.D. Nwani  |     Nigeria   | NA
Fundulus rubrifrons |BOLD:AAI7245 |  John Donavan  |  United States| NA
Eutrigla gurnardus  |BOLD:AAC0262 |Hermann Neumann |    North Sea  | NA
Sprattus sprattus   |BOLD:AAE9187 |Hermann Neumann |    North Sea  | NA
Gadus morhua        |BOLD:ACF1143 |Hermann Neumann |    North Sea  | NA
Tilapia zillii      |BOLD:AAB9042 |     C.D. Nwani |      Nigeria  | NA
Gadus morhua        |BOLD:ACF1169 |   Angela Cicia |  United States| NA
```

Going down the rows, basically a species can have only one BIN or more than one, and the same BIN can occasionally be assigned to different species.

So what I'm trying to do is fill the column assigning the grade "E" to every species that is assigned to a BIN which is itself assigned to more than 1 different species; the grade "D" for every species that has less than 3 occurrences in this first dataframe; "C" to the species that are assigned more than 1 different BIN but at the same time each of the BINs assigned to that particular species are assigned to only one species; "B" for the species that are assigned to only one BIN but every one of its specimens are collected from the same collector and in the same country; and finally "A" for every species that has only one BIN assigned to it but has specimens collected from more than one different collector or in more than one country.

So what I've done is creating a new dataframe that includes a column with how many BINs are assigned to each species (bin_per_species); another one with a column showing how many species are present for each BIN number (species_per_bin); another one with a column showing how many collector exist for each species (collectors_per_species); and finally one with a column on how many countries are assigned to each species (country_per_species)

```
#creating the other dataframe from the first one 

fish_13=fish_12%>% 
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarise(occurrence = n_distinct(BIN),
            BIN = str_c(unique(BIN), collapse = ","))

names(fish_13)=c("species","bin_per_species","BIN")
View(fish_13)

fish_14=fish_12%>% 
  group_by(BIN) %>%
  summarise(occurrence = n_distinct(species),
            species = str_c(unique(species), collapse = ","))

names(fish_14)=c("BIN","species_per_bin","species")
View(fish_14)
length(unique(fish_14$BIN))

fish_15=fish_12%>% 
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarise(occurrence = n_distinct(collectors),
            collectors = str_c(unique(collectors), collapse = ","))
names(fish_15)=c("species","collector_per_species","collectors")
View(fish_15)

fish_16=fish_12%>% 
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarise(occurrence = n_distinct(country),
            country = str_c(unique(country), collapse = ","))
names(fish_16)=c("species","countries_per_species","country")
View(fish_16)
```

So from here I tried forming the conditions with various if/else functions but the problems I'm having are that the dataframes have different lengths and I can't assign all the grades from A to E at the same time because even when I manage to have no errors, some of them are converted back to NA. The output I wanted is basically the first dataframe, with every specimen having a grade assigned to it.

Sorry if I'm being confusing and presenting the data in a wrong way but I'm new to this community and I'm trying to get better. Thank you in advance for any response

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to SO.

Now about your question: I felt a little confuse trying to understand all the rules but I'm thinking the solution may be easy.

You have these rules mainly based on BIN row, iterate these values and do a subset from the data, then you apply a function to check the rules and update the grade.

Like this:

```
bins = unique(fish_12$BIN)
for(b in bins) {
    # Get the index so you can update only the grade of the subset
    sub_fish_index = which(fish_12$BIN == b)
    sub_fish_data = fish_12[,sub_fish_index]

    # use a function to identiffy the patterns and apply the rules (return a vector of rules)
    new_grade = apply_rules(sub_fish_data)

    # Update grade in the main data.frame
    fish_12$grade[sub_fish_index] = new_grade
}
```

I returned a vector of grades because some rules may be able to use this information and set the correct grade.

I hope this helps you.